# Trig and Inverse Trig Function Compositions

Tags: trigonometry, inverse, function-and-relation-composition

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I honestly tried searching and all I could find was obvious stuff like $\sin(\arcsin(x)) = x$

So what is the logic behind simplifying expressions like this, where there is a constant or something else along with the $\arcsin(x)$?

$\sin(2\arcsin(x))=2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$, and also $$\cos \arcsin x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\arcsin x)}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ Therefore $$\sin 2\arcsin x=2\sin \arcsin x\cos\arcsin x=2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

However, make sure to check that the signs are correct. Technically $$\cos \theta=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$$

Comment: I facepalmed so hard when I read the first line of your answer. I can't believe I didn't think of that! But anyway, thanks so much.

Comment: lol no problem :)